# Kivy. Why size_hint doesn't work at widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I want to scale an image in Widget using `size_hint`, but it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class Game(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(size=[1280, 960])
        self.add_widget(Image(source='img.jpg', size_hint=(1, 1)))


class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        gm = Game()
        return gm


GameApp().run()
```

As a result I see a black window with a 100x100 image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding your `Image` to a class that extends `Widget`. The `Widget` class is not intended as a container, and does not handle things like `size_hint`. So, I suggest changing `Game` to extend some type of container, like `FloatLayout`. Here is your code with that change:

```
class Game(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(size=[1280, 960])
        self.add_widget(Image(source='img.jpg', size_hint=(1,1), allow_stretch=True))
```

You may need the `allow_stretch=True` to allow the `Image` to stretch the source.

Answer (score 0):

## Question

> Why `size_hint` doesn't work for Widget?

### Answer

1. The keyword, `size_hint` that you have provided, is not applying to the
   Widget. It is applying to the `Image` object. [The base class of `Image` widget is a Widget](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html#api). [The default size of a widget is (100, 100) and default size_hint is (1, 1)](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html). Therefore, by providing `size_hint=(1, 1)` when instantiating an Image widget, you are not changing the default `size_hint` or `size`.
2. When you provided `size=[1280, 960]` to the super constructor, you have already overrode the default `size` of the widget of (100, 100) or default `size_hint` of (1, 1)

### Solution

If you add `pos=self.pos, size=self.size, allow_stretch=True)` to `Image`, you will get an image displayed.

But there is still a black strip at the bottom.

#### Snippets

`self.add_widget(Image(source='Jupiter.png', pos=self.pos, size=self.size, allow_stretch=True))`

## Recommended Solution.

You can replace `Image` object by doing the following:

1. Use the Widget's `canvas` to display an image in a `Rectangle`
2. Bind the Widget's `pos` and `size` to a method to `redraw` the image
3. Add import statement, `from kivy.graphics import Rectangle`

### Snippets

```
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle

class Game(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(size=[1280, 960])
        with self.canvas:
            self.rect = Rectangle(source="Jupiter.png", pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
        self.bind(pos=self.redraw, size=self.redraw)

    def redraw(self, *args):
        self.rect.size = self.size
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
```

### Output

[image: Recommnded Solution]